# Google apps settings deleted

Tags: settings

I just deleted the Google apps settings by mistake (from `Applications -> Google Apps -> clear data`). So, my HTC Magic is not connecting to the Google server anymore. How can I input the dates I've deleted? Can it be reinstalled?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about HTC, but you can probably configure your Google account in `Settings > Accounts`.